# iOS 7- Results of Google Places API response

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I am developing an iOS application using google places API. Here is an example of my NSURLRequest:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.703380,4.204390&radius=25000&types=cafe&sensor=true&key=myAppKey.

As a result i get the following json response:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],.
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

But when i open google maps site on the browser to search cafe around the same location:(48.703380,4.204390)
i found some places where the distance is < 25 km (the radius which i use in my request).

Is there any explanation for this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change types to type in the url request

Comment: Thanks Bro :) ! I need a lesson of concentration :). i will check it as a right answer.